# how to create wordpress video gallery using custom post type

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website where i am displaying videos using youtube embeds in a bootstrap grid layout.

I wish to make things more manageable by keeping all the videos under a custom post type called videos. I have created the custom post type but the post needs to be opened individually to view the video. please guide me on how to display the video thumbnail with the play button and directly play the video on the videos page.

I am not using any existing wordpress video gallery plugin as none of them offers two column layout with video descriptions in their free package.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for someone to write the code for you. Questions are more likely to get a useful response here if you do some research and try to solve it then raise specific questions.

Comment: if I was in your place I will use video plugin .

Comment: Thank You, I am not asking for code. And i cannot afford paid plugins. I just need some guidance on how to approach this problem. Some plugin or how-to.

Answer (score -1):

no one will write the code for you ... if you have spisific problem people will gladly help you

my sugestion is use some plugin like :

http://codecanyon.net/item/youtuber-unique-youtube-videos-plugin/12966835?s_phrase=video%20gallery&s_rank=10

free plugins :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-video/screenshots/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contus-video-gallery/screenshots/

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/best-wordpress-youtube-gallery-plugins/

https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-gallery/examples/wordpress-youtube-video-gallery-id10/

Comment: Thank You, I am not asking for code. And i cannot afford paid plugins. I just need some guidance on how to approach this problem. Some plugin or how-to.

Comment: there is many free plugins to do the same . also did you conside the wordpress default gallery

Comment: i tried a lot of free plugins but the free versions lack layout customizations. hence is resorted to using custom post types.

Comment: if you want to go with custom post solution ... be more spisific about the problem you have